# How to fix status code = 400 while PUT data into content-type strapi?

Tags: strapi

Got the issue `Bad request, status 400` while adding the content to the existing Content-Type.

Tested on strapi v18.6, v18.7, v19.3

Found similar issue on github https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/5095

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I found when the error occurs.

> Each time when I update the **Content-type which name starts from some
>   numeric value** I got that error. The error is NOT occurring if the
>   Content-type starts with some character.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with QraphQL plugin. It fails if a Content Type name starts with a number. The issues should be fixed soon.

To get more information - check official GitHub https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/5095#issuecomment-595870672